# Probability to choose bad screw

Tags: probability

I have this task:

> Carpenter using bolts from two different factories - factory X and Y.
>   40% from his bolts are from factory X and 60% from factory Y. 4% of
>   bolts from factory X are bad and 2% from factory Y are bad. What are
>   the chances to choose bad bolt from all bolts?

My solution is $P = 0,028$ but I dont know this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(bad)=P(bad\mid X)P(X)+P(bad \mid Y)P(Y)=0.4\cdot0.04+0.6\cdot0.02=0.028$$

Comment: why $0.4 . 0.04 + 0.6 . 0.02 = 0.136$ ?

Comment: I corrected it...